# FormData not working in Internet Explorer?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, xmlhttprequest, form-data

```
    function uploadPhoto(file) {
    if (!file || !file.type.match(/image.*/)){
        if(!file){
            postStatus();
        } else {
            return;
        }
    }
    var fd = new FormData();
    fd.append("image", file);
    fd.append("privacy", document.getElementById('privacy-handler').value);
    var xhr = GetXmlHttpRequest(); 
    xhr.open("POST", "url here");
    slideUp('photo-upload');
    slideDown('photo-manager-txt');
    document.getElementById("photo-manager-txt").innerHTML='<i>Please wait a moment while we process your photo.</i>';
    xhr.onload = function() {
        if(xhr.responseText == '0'){
            document.getElementById('photo-manager-txt').innerHTML='<br />Photo upload failed';
            slideDown('photo-upload');
            return;
        } else {
            document.getElementById('photo-txt').value='grab?v=1&file='+xhr.responseText;
            document.getElementById('photo-manager-txt').innerHTML='Photo uploaded and shared.';
            postStatus();
        }
    }
    xhr.send(fd);
}
```

This function seems not to be working. When I call the function I'm using:

```
onClick="uploadPhoto(document.getElementById('ID-HERE').files[0]);"
```

When I remove the `0` from `files[]`, it atleast runs `postStatus();`, but it won't upload the photo. How do I go about fixing this?

Comment: What version of IE are you talking about?

Comment: [caniuse.com file api](http://caniuse.com/#search=file%20api)

Comment: Well I think that's the problem, @Jake. The file API isn't supported until IE10.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The XHR in IE doesn't support FormData until IE10. You may install Windows 8 Customer Preview to have a try.