# jQuery AJAX Uploading system IE issue

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, internet-explorer

I have problem with `Internet Explorer`

Here is a sample of script with AJAX and jQuery and works fine in other browsers but in `IE` it doesn't

index.html

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    <input name="file" type="file" multiple="true" id="file" />
    <input type="button" value="Upload" /> or clic "U"
</form>
```

ajax.js

```
$(':button').click(function(){
    var formData = new FormData($('form')[0]);
    $("#data").html(formData);
    $.ajax({
        url: 'upload.php',  //server script to process data
        type: 'POST',
        xhr: function() {  // custom xhr
            myXhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
            if(myXhr.upload){ // check if upload property exists
                myXhr.upload.addEventListener('progress',progressHandlingFunction, false); // for handling the progress of the upload
            }
            return myXhr;
        },
        //Ajax events
        //beforeSend: beforeSendHandler,
        success: function(html) {
            $("#php").html(html);
            $("#file").val('');
        },
        error:function(html) {
            $("#php").html(html);
        },
        enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
        // Form data
        data: formData,
        //Options to tell JQuery not to process data or worry about content-type
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false
    });
});
```

Works fine in other browsers but in `Opera` and `IE` it is not working.

This is the CONSOLE(`F12`) erron on `IE`

```
SCRIPT5009: 'FormData' is undefined 
ajax.js, line 53 character 9
```

What should I do to solve the problem?

Comment: Press F12 in IE, go to the console tab, then trigger your code. It should output an error. Paste that error in your question

Comment: SCRIPT5009: 'FormData' is undefined 
    ajax.js, line 53 character 9 this is the code

Answer (score 0):

> SCRIPT5009: 'FormData' is undefined ajax.js, line 53 character 9 this is the code

Assuming your error lies here, move your method for `FormData` above the code you posted above.

Example:

```
function FormData (form) {
   ....
}

$(':button').click(function(){
    var formData = new FormData($('form')[0]);
    $("#data").html(formData);
    $.ajax({
        url: 'upload.php',  //server script to process data
        type: 'POST'...
```

**EDIT**

Apparently, `FormData` is not supported in IE. You may, however, be able to use jQuery's `serialize` like so:

```
var formData = $('form').serialize();
```

Comment: yess sure but what to do inside the function FormData (...) cus im beginer in java
???

Comment: @ex3m.al You should already have a function like that somewhere... Maybe in a plugin that you're including?

Comment: i dont have any plugin exept jquery.min.1.6.js

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't realize FormData was a function built into the browser. It's not supported in IE http://stackoverflow.com/a/9578251/628859

Comment: Edited with a possible alternative

Comment: @Kylie Macey in windows 8 and latest browsers it works fine

did you tested with jQuery `serialize` ??

Answer (score 0):

FormData class is only available for html 5 and html5 is supported on the latest version of the browser.

the problem is for IE even the latest has some security issue for uploading multiple files through ajax but u can upload one file.

if u insist uploading with ajax its better to use iframe or flash object to upload in the old browsers