# Image upload functionality is not working in internet explorer while using formdata

Tags: ajax

Why image upload functionality is not working in internet explorer9 if I am using multipart/form-data to take image data.
How can I upload image in internet explorer.

This is my code that i am using to upload image.

```
      var formData = new FormData($('form')[1]);


    var onclick_attr=$('#Upload').attr('onclick');
     $.ajax({
            url: '${pageContext.servletContext.contextPath}/UploadImage',
            data: formData,
            type: 'POST',
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            beforeSend: function(xhr) {
                $('#process-img-div').hide();
                $('#uploading-img').show();
                $('#Upload').attr('onclick','').css('opacity','0.5');
                $('#loader-imgforlogo').show();
            },
            success: function(xhr) {

                var str = xhr.split('&');
                for(var i=0; i<str.length; i++) {
                    var keys = str[i].split(':');
                    if(keys[0]=='Name')
                        fileName = keys[1];
                    else if(keys[0]=='Width')
                        imgWidth = keys[1];
                    else if(keys[0]=='Height')
                        imgHeight = keys[1];
                    else if(keys[0]=='Path')
                        filePath = keys[1];
                    }

                $('#preview').attr({
                               'src':'${pageContext.servletContext.contextPath}/uploads/'+fileName
                });

                $('#process-img-div').show();
                $('#uploading-img').hide();
            },
            complete:function(jqXHR, textStatus){
                $('#Upload').attr('onclick',onclick_attr).css('opacity','1');
                $('#loader-imgforlogo').hide();
                $.fancybox.close(); 

            },
            error: function(xhr) {

            }
    });
     }
```

Comment: what you have written in File : UploadImage ?

Answer (score 1):

FormData object is not supported in Internet Explorer until IE10. IE9 doesn't support FormData Object. So it wouldn't work with IE9
Check the [supported browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/XMLHttpRequest/FormData) for FormData Object

Also take a look of another similar issue
[FormData not working in Internet Explorer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9573607/formdata-not-working-in-internet-explorer)

For the older browsers that doesn't support FormData object, you can first check if the browser supports it here [How can I check if the browser support HTML5 file upload (FormData object)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7296426/how-can-i-check-if-the-browser-support-html5-file-upload-formdata-object)

If the browser doesn't support you can traverse the form dom elements and create a json object to set as $.ajax method data attribute value. If you are uploading any files take a look at [Iframe Upload Solution](http://www.jainaewen.com/files/javascript/jquery/iframe-post-form.html)